# Is it advisable to put the CSS Background Property in the HTML tag or in the Body?

Tags: css, styles

I have seen a website using google chrome that they put the CSS Background Property in the HTML tag like this:

```
html { background: #eee url('../img/bg.jpg') center center repeat fixed; }
```

Is it ok to do that or should i put it in the body?

Comment: Put it in the body to enforce structure of webpage.

Comment: try http://validator.w3.org/ and see for yur self. From my guts I ould say its the wrong place, the html tag should (in my opinion) only contain the header and body tags.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter on which you put the background, both work equally good, but there is a gotcha.

If you put the background on `BODY` only, the background will stretch the whole height of the screen, even if there's no content on the page, but if you put it on both `HTML` and `BODY`, the background on `BODY` will only be as high as your content inside it, just like on any `DIV`.

I often use backgrounds on both when there's a need for two background images as this eliminates the need for unnecessary `DIV` wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

[lea.verou.me](http://lea.verou.me/) puts it on the html tag. If it's good enough for her, then it's good enough for you. ;)

You might want to throw `height: 100%;` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a page wide background image on the `body` tag.

```
<body>
```

And in your style sheet you can then specify a background

```
body
 {
   background-image:url('blah.jpg');
 }
```